# composer autoload phpmailer classes

Tags: php, composer-php

Hi I'm new to composer and trying to understand how it works, so I've installed on my local machine and it works fine, I've managed to installa phpmailer version 6.
I've created a function to send email using smtp and put insside the file function.php then I've got the file config.php wher ei've included the composer autoloder file. 
In the php file where I call the function to send the email i've included the config.php and the function.php but i get the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found
```

So i've included in the functions.php outside my function the following code

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

and it seems to work fine. My understanding is that i can load this class inside composer.json is it correct? I'm not sure as i said I'm new to composer and any help would be appreciated
Many thanks

Comment: When you have this kind of issue  please try to include file of work so that we can comprehend.I propose you to edit your question with more details

Comment: never mind i've managed to make it work. I've changed $mail = new PHPMailer; with $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true); into my function and in the composer.json added "vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer" into the autoloader